# Maven pom multi module build with selected module build profiles

Tags: maven, build, module, pom.xml, profile

I have a multi module pom project that just basically includes multiple maven project modules to run them on specific sequence. The problem is that each of these modules have multiple build profiles. How can I select the build profile for each of the module when building the main pom project or is it even possible?

Comment: How is the sequence determined?

Comment: @khmarbaise It builds them in the sequence they are written in the modules block, am I right? At least it seems to do so far :) <modules><module>module1</module><module>module2</module></modules>

Comment: You should never rely on the order of written them in the pom file. You should always define correct dependencies between the modules...Furthermore why do you have so many profiles? Sounds wrong to me...There are situations where you need profiles but the less the better...

Comment: @khmarbaise The modules have correct dependencies set between modules. Though if module x is dependant on module y and I build first module x and then y then building the module y later is useless since x uses older module y build. This is why I want to build them on correct order and it seems to do that just fine and it ain't the problem here or  does the documentation say somewhere that I should not trust the order? Profiles are used just to separate different kind of configurations and such between different environments. This is just how is.

Comment: The build order is automatically determined by Maven itself. I was just astonished that you explicitly said defined the order yourself which is based on the automatic character not needed nor necessary. As I asked before can you give some details or examples of different profiles and why do you have different ones in different childs? For environments ? What kind of differences do you have?

Comment: @khmarbaise They are different because they are not really child projects per se. They are all separate projects that some of them may or may not have dependency on another. Because they are separate projects, the build profiles are also different. Some may have profiles that are named the same way though. There is though main project that has dependencies on some of these projects, which is why main should be built last. So some of the modules work like libraries that have build profiles. I cannot give example on profiles but as I said, they are used to separate configs between environments.

Comment: So this means this project is NOT a multi module build but it sounds it should be...Pleasae show some pom file examples...

Comment: @khmarbaise Each project has its own pom files as they are own projects (modules). Currently the main project is just a pom project that has the modules set in pom so that by building the main project it builds the other modules and gives the final package to use. This works otherwise fine but I have to now manually select the correct profiles when building and I'd like to automate it. I'd like to keep this question in general level.